# Fake smtp server with TLS

Tags: c#, smtp, automated-tests, tls1.2

Is someone know fake smtp server, like [nDumbster](http://ndumbster.sourceforge.net/default.html), but with TLS support?
It needed to make some functional tests of API.
nDumbster fully suited except TLS.

Big thanks.
Also sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

I think [SMTP4Dev](https://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/) may support it.  You just have to check the options for STARTTLS.

SMTP4Dev seems to crash on me though when I use the STARTTLS options.  So, I created my own project [Origami SMTP](https://travispessetto.github.io/OrigamiSMTP). It has its limitations right now with include not being able to handle authorization, in other words you must use it without a login and the certificates are not trusted, which may or may not be a problem.

[image: Picture of Origami GUI]

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Mailnest.io. It is one of the best email testing platform available and is affordable. It also has a free plan for limited usage.